# How to Intercept another app so that it pause it's process unit I remove the overlay screen in android Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, foreground-service

I am trying to build an app locker. I can display an overlay Screen, but I want that locked app to be paused until the user opens it. The problem here is Sometimes When the activity of another app launches in the background my app is terminated(maybe by Android OS). How to deal with this?

Comment: Can you please explain how is this question r elated to Firebase?

Comment: @AlexMamo that was a mistake, but could you please tell me the answer?